# gae session data not updated

Tags: google-app-engine, guice

I'm using guice 4.0 on current java app engine and have the problem that changes to my `@SessionScoped` classes are not persisted (on the production system). After initialising the session objects, changes are not persistend.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my question seems to be unclear, it actually was: Wy the hell are my session objects not persisted?

A working solution for me was to manually change session attributes directly on the HttpSession whenever I want to persist changes in my session objects:

`updateSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession s = request.getSession(false);
    if (s != null) {
        if (s.getAttribute("_") != null)
            s.removeAttribute("_");
        else
            s.setAttribute("_", "");
    }
}`